# Basic view consuming too much CPU

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After executing a segue to the second view of my application, CPU usage goes from 0% to 100% or more. This second view is very trivial. It has a couple of views: a text box, two buttons, one label and one image, basically. The view-controller has few code as well, basically is that (I'm just omitting one button click implementation):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var userNameText: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad() 
  }

   @IBAction func cancelButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   @IBAction func nextButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
      // code executed when clicked, but CPU is already 100% before clicking
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }
 }
```

I used X-Code Instruments, but I didn't find any useful information besides the high CPU and battery usage. My last suspicion is the way views is placed or maybe their constraints or props is requiring processing.

Any idea?

Comment: On Simulator or on device? Do you have any useful output in the console (such as constraints error) when executing the segue?

Comment: The code you have shown would not use up so much CPU, are you using a simulator? a device?

Comment: I'm using a device. Iphone SE. I will check for constraints errors on console.

Comment: No console errors. I removed everything from the view in the story board, it was left only "Safe Area" and I couldn't remove it somehow. Still CPU usage 100% just by opening a black screen.

Comment: @Murilo - Take a look at [mcve] --- next to impossible to figure this out without a complete example that reproduces what you are seeing.